# Ruby on Rails - Seed undefined method error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seed, seeding

In my application I have `Post` & `Slide` Models. `post has many slides` & `slide belongs_to post`.

**All** of my slides has one image each *(I'm using `carrierwave gem` for uploading)*, but currently some of my posts doesn't have a image.

Im trying to grab the **First slide** of each post and upload its image to the post with help of `seed`.

This is what I have tried in `seeds.rb`:

```
posts = Post.all.where(image: nil)

posts.each do |post|
  slide = Slide.where(post_id: post).order('created_at DESC').first
  post.update(remote_image_url: slide.image_url(:thumb_huge))
end
```

*AND*

```
posts = Post.all.where(image: nil)

posts.each do |post|
  slide = Slide.where(post_id: post).order('created_at DESC').first
  post.update(remote_image_url: "http://mywebsite.com/uploads/slide/image/#{slide}/#{slide.image}")
end
```

When I run this, I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method image' for nil:NilClass`

Why do I get `NoMethodError` for `image` and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to show the code,  but I`m guessing since post doesn't have an image, you need to first create the associated model instance.

Comment: change `posts = Post.all.where(image: nil)` to `posts = Post.where(image: nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have  `post` that doesn't have any slides, so

`Slide.where(post_id: post).order('created_at DESC').first`

is returning `nil`.

Simply checking that `slide` exists should fix it.

```rb
posts.each do |post|
  slide = Slide.where(post_id: post).order('created_at DESC').first

  if slide.present? 
     post.update(remote_image_url: "http://mywebsite.com/uploads/slide/image/#{slide}/#{slide.image}")
  end
end
```

However, if you have your `belongs_to` and `has_many` relations setup correctly, you can simplify this a bit:

```rb
posts.each do |post|
  if post.slides.any?
     slide = post.slides.first
     post.update(remote_image_url: "http://mywebsite.com/uploads/slide/image/#{slide}/#{slide.image}")
  end
end
```

Or you could go even further and only select the posts that have at least one slide in the first place:

```rb
posts = Post.joins(:slides).uniq

posts.each do |post|
  slide = post.slides.first
  post.update(remote_image_url: "http://mywebsite.com/uploads/slide/image/#{slide}/#{slide.image}")
end
```

Comment: Thanks @nburkley. When I run either of solution, it only runs `select` and not `update`. **This is in my terminal:**  Slide Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "slides".* FROM "slides" WHERE "slides"."post_id" = 7257  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
      01    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      01    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK`

Comment: It looks like when I am *selecting* `slide` it only run the `Slide Load` and not the `post update`. I tested by removing the `slide = post.slides.first` out of `posts.each do`, then post update was ran. But how can I select the `slide` if I have it out-side of `posts.each do`

Comment: If you're seeing `ROLLBACK` in the logs it's because the `update` is failing. There's probably some validation logic preventing the model from saving. Try adding some logging or a breakpoint to find why it won't save - here is how could add a point `binding.pry unless post.update(..your changes here..)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to just put one condition in your code.

```
 posts.each do |post|
   if post.slides.count > 0
     slide = Slide.where(post_id: post).order('created_at DESC').first
     post.update(remote_image_url: slide.image_url(:thumb_huge))
   end
 end
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Divyang. When I run your solution, it only runs `select` and not `update`. **This is in my terminal:** Slide Load (0.3ms) SELECT "slides".* FROM "slides" WHERE "slides"."post_id" = 7257 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 01 (0.1ms) BEGIN 01 (0.1ms) ROLLBACK

Comment: can you add complete log of query?

Comment: As Mentioned, its just **Slide Load (0.3ms) SELECT "slides".* FROM "slides" WHERE "slides"."post_id" = 7257 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 01 (0.1ms) BEGIN 01 (0.1ms) ROLLBACK** and only thing changes is the `post_id`

Comment: It looks like when I am *selecting* `slide` it only run the `Slide Load` and not the `post update`. I tested by removing the `slide = post.slides.first` out of `posts.each do`, then post update was ran. But how can I select the `slide` if I have it out-side of `posts.each do`